# Message broker by spring?

Tags: java, spring, messagebroker

Is there a message broker module spring  by spring ? I know spring integration is a module but that is ESB implementation and much more than message broker.
Does spring provides the dedicated message broker module  or we have to use external message broker. I did not get any complete example of spring message 
broker

Comment: Spring has had JMS support and message driven POJOs for a long time.  I'm not sure what you are thinking when you say message broker.  Spring Integration is NOT an ESB.  It's an implementation of all the classes in Hophe's Enterprise Integration: https://www.amazon.com/Enterprise-Integration-Patterns-Designing-Deploying/dp/0321200683/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1471095347&sr=8-1&keywords=enterprise+integration

Comment: when you say `Spring Integration is NOT an ESB`  . Does it mean both Spring integration and ESB both are solution for enterprise application integration(EAI) but through different approaches. But at `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus` i see  `spring integration` mentioned under `Existing ESB products`. so to me looks like Sprint integration implements ESB architectural pattern

Comment: It certainly maps the ideas that ESBs rely on, but I wouldn't call it an ESB.  Besides, ESB is an out of date, SOAP-y, heavy technology that has been passed by in favor of REST and cloud.  Spring Integration will be far more useful in modern architectures.